Javascript Promises: Why does resolve variable need to be accepted in the Promise ()?
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved');
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function asyncCall() {
  console.log('calling');
  const result = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
  console.log(result);
  // Expected output: "resolved"
}

asyncCall();

My question is on the return new Promise((resolve) => { line. Why does resolve need to be passed into the Promise?
What type is resolve? How is it available?
Tried searching google.

The Promise API ensures that a reference to a resolver function is passed into the Promise callback. You don't have to pass it; the system does.

Do you have to accept it? Well, no. But then you have no way to actually resolve the promise, which probably would make it fairly pointless. So practically speaking: yes.
